# Why did Gintoki scream "Psycho-Pass!"?

Tags: gintama

I just watched the first episode of the new Gintama 2015 season. At the beginning, when Gintoki was hit by a chair, he screamed *Psycho-Pass!*

I know Psycho-Pass is another anime (I watched it) - but what was the meaning behind that reference in Gintama? I was wondering if both animes had the same studio or something, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I am not so sure but as I was searching for psycho pass - gintama connections and got that : 
[Hijikata Toushiro and Kougami Shinya (from Psycho-Pass)](http://forums.yorozuyasoul.com/index.php?topic=1417.15) 
it might be related!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gintoki screaming **Psycho-Pass!** when hit by a chair,

[image: Gin gets hit by a chair]

is a reference to a scene (episode 17 at 18:21) from *Psycho-Pass*, where Kasei gets hit on the face with a portable patient monitor by Makishima.

[image: Kasei gets hit by a portable monitor]

Gintama is well known for using gags and references regarding other anime. Most references are made when the situation is similar to that of the other anime. This Psycho-Pass reference is a new one.

I also believe it could be a word which was misheard by the viewers. Found this on [Yorozuya Soul Forums (dead link)](https://forums.yorozuyasoul.com/index.php?topic=3001.45). The author has a good point.

> Gin had shouted a lot of random words before, when he gets hit or blown away, maybe it's just a random thing, I personally think that maybe he actually said "**psychopath**" but the translator though he said Psycho-Pass, since they are both pronounce the same way (Psycho-Pass is a pun), at least that's my assumption, I could be wrong, it's not like I'm fluent in Japanese(YET!)

Comment: If it really was the intended pun, he should have been hit with a book...

Comment: @Mints97 not necessarily. The similarity kinda lies in the way both faces are attacked by an object. I dont think Gintama meant to recreate that exact scene from Psycho-Pass.

Comment: It's a reasonable answer. But I do agree with @Mints97 that the joke would have been a lot easier to get and even funnier had it been a book.

Comment: @Omega agreed. I couldn't find any other references.. But since Gin has yelled random stuff before, and throwing a book would mean exact replication, I think its explainable. Maybe the concept of this reference was to confuse the viewers and let their imagination decide what really happened :p

Comment: I don't think it's the first hit on the face that is being referenced, but the second (Psycho-Pass episode 17 at 18:20): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjhZ78d4RZQ&t=18m20s. Same angle.

Comment: Ooh that seems like better answer than mine. Please do make it as an answer. The credit goes to.you for finding it out :) @Gao